# Opengl 3d texture sampling

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am trying to create a 3d texture that consists of a grid of random values, but whenever I sample in the fragment shader I just get a very very small value - even if I just set it to a grid of 0.5's or something like that!

This is how I tried to do it:

```
static GLuint noise_tex = 0;

//create grid of random numbers:
int tex_width = 256;
int tex_height = 256;
int tex_depth = 256;
int tex_size = tex_width*tex_height*tex_depth;
GLfloat* noise_data = new GLfloat[tex_size];
for (int i = 0; i < tex_size; i++){
      noise_data[i] = static_cast <GLfloat> (rand()) / static_cast <GLfloat> (RAND_MAX);
}

//create and bind texture
glGenTextures(1, &noise_tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D,noise_tex);

//set filtering and wrapping
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_REPEAT);

glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_R16F, tex_width, tex_height, tex_depth, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, noise_data);
```

And in the fragment shader (not what I want to do in the end, but just to see what value height has):

```
 in vec3 pos;

 uniform sampler3D noise_tex;

 out vec4 fragColor;

 void main()
 {

     float height = texture(noise_tex, pos).r;

     if(height<0.000001){
         fragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0,1.0,1.0);
     }
     else if .... etc

 }
```

I haven't created any texture coordinates, but I just assumed that it would work when using GL_repeat and GL_linear - I know that pos lies in the interval pos.x: 200-300, pos.y: 200-300, pos.z: 0-10, so I also considered mapping these values to 0-1, but that didn't seem to be the problem either.

Comment: Try creating the `noise_data` array differently. Declare it like this: `GLfloat[tex_size] noise_data;` and pass it to `glTexImage3D()` as `&noise_data`. Also, the GLSL texture lookup function always expects normalized coordinates. Therefore, you will have to map the values in `pos` to the interval [0,1].

Comment: The values are going to be between 0 and 1, if you do if (height < 0.000001) then all of the pixels will be black. I've tried it on my program and this works, if I set it to height < 0.5 I get a kinda noise image. Maybe show your vertex shader. And also how do you upload your vec3 positions?
http://tinypic.com/r/2vv9jip/9

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - I tried mapping the values to 0-1 again and suddenly it worked :)